# VS 2015 unit testing with web api 5

Tags: c#, rest, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

I have a web api `MVC5 REST` service running in IIS Express under VS 2015.
I want to write unit tests to excercise the `REST` services.
I want to be testing the `REST` services syntax and output, not the controller.
My problem is gettin the IIS Express service to be started on a known port when the test starts. How can I configure/code this to make sure that IIS Express is started. *(I also noticed a "web" profile in the Web API project's debug section. It seems to start the service as a console. But I can't figure out how to make use of that.)*

Comment: web api 5??, I think current version is 2

Comment: See http://blog.kloud.com.au/2014/10/26/asp-net-web-api-integration-testing-with-one-line-of-code/